# Many editable items on a single page

Tags: html, forms

I have a page where a user can edit a large (~) amount of small items with a very few options, like remove, turn off, turn on and edit name of the item.

I don't know why but the current approach I'm using does not give me the "good code" feeling. I create a form for each action on each item, so I have like 3 forms per item. I feel like forms were meant to submit larger amounts of information.

Fortunately, I found the form* attributes html5 offers (HTML5, yayy!) that kind of allow for this. I created a single delete form on the page and then on each item I added a button, outside of the form.

```
<button type="submit" form="delete_form" name="item-id" value="1">Delete</button>
```

Unfortunately that is not the case with the edit-name form. If I add a single form on the page, then have input elements for the name on every item, like

```
<input name="item-name" type="text" form="update_form"/>
<button type="submit" form="update_form" name="item-id" value="1">Update</button>

...

<input name="item-name" type="text" form="update_form"/>
<button type="submit" form="update_form" name="item-id" value="2">Update</button>
```

Then on the landing page, `item-name` will always be the last input's value. I haven't tested this but I am assuming that when submitting the form all input fields pointing to that form with their `form` attribute are being collected and sent, then on the other side they are all being processed and I'm getting the last one since they all have the same name and are being overwritten.

How, if at all, can I have only a certain input be submitted, depending on which button was clicked, instead of all?

*Notice*: I can think of hacky ways like including the item id in the input name but it doesn't seem right, also what if there is no id at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a specific button should only post a specific input, then making separate forms sounds like the right way to go.

Your assumption is right, by the way, so another solution would be to put all inputs in the same form, but give them different names, indeed based on an item id. Adding a unique ID or name is the right way to go. After all, how would you know what you are editing if you have no ID? Currently the ID is in the button too, right? You need it.

Anyway, with such a form you can save them all with one click on a submit button.

From a UX perspective, maybe that's a better approach too. Now you would have to do and save each edit separately, which results in a page refresh, which can be annoying and slow.

I would make a form in two versions.

*Non-Javascript*

The basic form shows all the items to edit, each followed by a group of radio buttons that allow you to update, delete, turn on, or turn off the item.

The form has one big submit button that posts the entire form. All items are updated or their state is changed depending on the radio buttons.

This way, a user can relatively easily edit all items and post their changes without a lot of page refreshes.

*JavaScript additions*

Using JavaScript/JQuery, you can modify the form. Change the radio buttons to normal buttons and perform the action using AJAX, but only for the item they belong. The big button at the end can be removed, and the form can be altered so it doesn't submit anymore. This way, a user has a rich interaction without the nuisance of the page being constantly reloaded.

Comment: I currently use AJAX, the page is not refreshed. I don't want to use the unique-name-for-each-input approach because then I will be sending a lot of unnecessary information over with each request. I guess I will stick with the 1 form per item solution for this particular option.

Comment: Good choice. That solution would of course work with AJAX very well, and the `< 1%` of users that don't have JavaScript enabled just have to deal with the page reloading.

Comment: I was just wondering, though, they went ahead and added those very handy attributes for inputs, but they didn't really think it through? I doubt that is the case, there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: They did think it through, and in some cases it's convenient to be able to position your form elements wherever you want. But in your case, you just want to save one item at a time and have a save button per item, so that's obviously a different use case in which having separate forms is the obvious choice.